# Compare Arrays for matching string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, compare, telnet

I have a script that telnets into a box, runs a command, and saves the output. I run another script after that which parses through the output file, comparing it to key words that are located in another file for matching. If a line is matched, it should save the entire line (from the original telnet-output) to a new file.

Here is the portion of the script that deals with parsing text:

```
def parse_file
    filter = []
    temp_file = File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\PARSED_TRIAL.txt', 'a+')
    t = File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\TRIAL_output_log.txt')
    filter = File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\Filtered_text.txt').readlines
    t.each do |line|
        filter.each do |segment|
            if (line =~ /#{segment}/)
                temp_file.puts line
            end
        end
    end
    t.close()
    temp_file.close()
end
```

Currently, it is only saving the last run string located in array `filter` and saving that to `temp_file`. It looks like the loop does not run all the strings in the array, or does not save them all. I have five strings placed inside the text file `Filtered_text.txt`. It only prints my last matched line into `temp_file`.

Comment: Are you looking for substring matches, or entire words? Currently you're going to get substring matches, and you'll skip any potential hits that don't match the character case.

Answer (score 4):

This (untested code) will duplicate the original code, only more succinctly and idiomatically:

```
filter = Regexp.union(File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\Filtered_text.txt').readlines.map(&:chomp))
File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\PARSED_TRIAL.txt', 'a+') do |temp_file|
  File.foreach('C:\Ruby193\scripts\TRIAL_output_log.txt') do |l|
    temp_file.puts l if (l[filter])
  end
end
```

To give you an idea what is happening:

```
Regexp.union(%w[a b c])
=> /a|b|c/
```

This gives you a regular expression that'll walk through the string looking for any substring matches. It's a case-sensitive search.

If you want to close those holes, use something like:

```
Regexp.new(
  '\b' + Regexp.union(
    File.open('C:\Ruby193\scripts\Filtered_text.txt').readlines.map(&:chomp)
  ).source + '\b',
  Regexp::IGNORECASE
)
```

which, using the same sample input array as above would result in:

```
/\ba|b|c\b/i
```